# Que extension se utiliza para que vs code me muestre snippets de firebase

Tags: firebase, vscode

Por ejemplo:

```
const descripcionSearch = this.angularFirestore
      .collection('users', (ref) => ref.where('descripcion', '==', palabra))
      .get();
```

Pero por ejemplo a la hora de escribir

```
this.angularFirestore.
```

no me aparece ningún tipo de ayuda. (La linea es una copiada de internet)

UPDATE: Tengo instalados todos los módulos de firebase necesarios y angular e typescript instalados

Answer (score 0):

Para poder lograr ver las funciones luego del punto deberias usar

```
npm install --save firebase
```

Ademas hay varios snippets que podes instalar que simplemente escribiendolos te autocompletan a lo que necesitas

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterHdd.firebase-firestore-snippets

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hasanakg.firebase-snippets